What is the length of an uncut steerer tube on the RockShox Rudy Ultimate XPLR?
Looking for a measurement of the factory length of an uncut steerer tube on a RockShox Rudy Ultimate XPLR gravel fork. Already tried the Google Fu, and spoke to SRAM service. They couldn't answer the question, though they did say they would escalate it and try to get back to me.
I'm trying to determine if I can order one for a bike that is exceptionally large, without having to just roll the dice.

Not an answer, but they are pretty long. The frame would have to be stupidly big for it not to work.

The rider plays pro basketball. The Fox version of the fork fits, but only gives room for one 10mm spacer with an uncut steerer.  Hoping the Rockshox might be a couple centimeters longer.  But SRAM doesn't publish the steerer tube length, as far as I can see.

I think you should order, then return if it's unsuitable. The distributor's warranty department will probabiy know though.

I am the retailer.  The distributor is supposed to be checking and getting back to me, but it's been 2 weeks.

Per RockShox, the answer is 300mm.They finally got back to me.
